# Proper behaviour for publicly available api resource requested using expired authorization token

Tags: rest, api, http-status-codes

I know there are already many 401 vs 403 questions, but that's **not** my case.

*What i'm asking is:* what should a server ideally do if the requested api resource is publicly available (does not *require* authorization) but the request includes an authorization header with a token that is either incorrect or expired?

*My reasoning is as follows:* in theory server could ignore it and respond, but this feels like a very bad idea. For example business logic behind processing the request could differ depending on being authenticated or not. Client app should also get an instant feedback that it should reauthenticate, and not only if and when it hits a non-public end-point.

Being "badly authenticated" and therefore implicitly treated as an anonymous is a somewhat undefined and confusing behaviour i think.

So to sum up. *Is it justified to use 400 in this particular case or is there any other, common practise?*

Answer (score 0):

If this API itself is publicly available, and by publicly available you mean doesn't require any authentication to the user, why will you return to the user a response with Bad Request? Think to yourself if it makes sense, if its public, you can bypass any kind of validation and save some processing on the server.

Related with this:

"but this feels like a very bad idea. For example business logic behind processing the request could differ depending on being authenticated or not."

I think that in this case, you should change the API itself to require authentication, and not accept any kind of unauthorized user, or a user with an expired token.

Sorry if I didn't help much, but this is my opinion on this.
If its badly authenticated then it's not a public API, right?
A public API would respond in any scenario, could just have some restriction on requests by second.

Comment: I'd have to disagree. Let's say i have a CMS where both the front- and back-end are SPAs. Unless you have some specific requirement - which i don't have - it makes perfect sense to create one api serving both applications. And there you have it - some end-points require authorization, some don't, and some differ in behaviour depending on authorization. For example if you're authenticated as an admin you're getting some non-public data about posts, users which anonymous users shouldn't ever see.

Comment: Anyway, my point was, that a request with invalid authorization is indeed bad / broken. Client assumes - for example - his authenticated as an admin, but api can't respond the way client assumes because authorization is invalid at this point. But responding with only the public data may be (_and probably is_) something totaly different than what the client expects. That's why i think api should respond with 400 (or with other bad request type of code).